# How many type of socket limit? What is their difference?

Tags: sockets, centos

I would like to know how many type of socket limit?
Is it just SOCK_STREAM and SOCK_DGRAM?

i have try ulimit -a. I am just wondering is all consider socket?

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 11716
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65535
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 11716
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: @ArihantGodha: what part of that page addresses this question? I don't see anything on it that does.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for CentOS, but in general other platforms do define additional socket types, such as `SOCK_RAW`, `SOCK_RDM`, and `SOCK_SEQPACKET`